# Creating signup form, No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a sign up form on Rails, and for some reason when I run my project, I get the error:

> No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}

Apologies for the newb question, but I'm not sure why? See my code below:

**`users_controller.rb`**:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new 
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
end
```

**`routes.rb`**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/new'

  get 'pages/home'

  get 'pages/howitworks'

  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/contact'

  get 'pages/becomeatechie'

  get 'signup' => 'users#new'

  root 'pages#home'
```

**`new.html.erb`**:

```
<% @page_title = "UserAuth | Signup" %>
<div class="Sign_Form">
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>

  <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
    <p> First name:</br> <%= f.text_field :firstname%> </p>
    <p> Last name:</br> <%= f.text_field :lastname%> </p>
    <p> Email:</br> <%= f.text_field :email%> </p>
    <p> Password:</br> <%= f.password_field :password%></p>
    <p> Password Confirmation:</br> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation%> </p>
    <%= f.submit :Signup %>
  <% end %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="Signup_Errors">
    <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
      <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post you `routes.rb` code in the question?

Comment: @Pavan see edit above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `resources :users` to your `routes.rb` file - it will generate the routes.

You can (and I insist you do so) read about routing [in rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm :) I'll accept your answer ASAP (stack won't let me for another 9 min...) Cheers!

Comment: @Brittany No problems. As I said, the link I provided would be very helpful for you, so go through it